# using partial view on asp.net core razor pages

Tags: asp.net, partial-views, razor-pages

I am developing a project that runs on asp.net core 2 razor pages.
I need a solution to load a partial view or component to in a RAZOR pages and also I could send come object (some class model or basic string).

this is detail pages which I want load partial view into.
Using this code :

```
@{
    await Html.RenderPartialAsync("Shared/Partial/DeleteModal", Model.DeleteModalModel);
}
```

this is my partial view inside

```
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header bg-red">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="defaultModalLabel">DİKKAT KAYIT SİLİNECEKTİR !</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">                
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="submit" asp-page-handler="Delete" class="btn bg-red m-t-15 waves-effect" value="Sil" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal" />
                <button type="button" class="btn bg-indigo m-t-15 waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => Model.ViewModel.Buttons.Close)</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

down is the partial view model

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace Q.Presentation.System.Razor.Pages.Shared.Partial
{
    public class DeleteModalModel : PageModel
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I want the set Message property from DETAIL page and want to show up on partial view which I want to load into DETAIL razor pages

Answer (score 5, accepted):

found a solution. when you add a partial razor view to project VS razor partial view template add **@page** top of the partial view CSHTML. 
You need to remove that to work properly.

this is the old partial view CSHTML file

```
@page
@model Project.Model

<div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
......
```

and the new one :

```
@model Project.Model

<div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
........
```

Comment: I just found my problem that removing @page on top then it works.
I just wonder why we have to do that? Can you explain to me, please?