# ASP.NET Core 2.0 Razor Pages web app separate Complex BindProperty Form

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor-pages

I am new to ASP.NET Core 2.0 Razor Pages web app framework. The problem is the following: I need to create html form for complex `[BindProperty]` class and separate it's complex fields in partial views or editors (like in MVC):

```
public class BasicInformation
{
    // complex filed
    public Name Name { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    // collection of objects
    public IEnumerable<Address> Addresses { get; set; }

    //complex field
    public PhoneNumber PhoneNumber { get; set; }

}
```

I would like to achieve something like this:

```
  <h4>BasicInformation</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Resume" />

                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.BasicInformation.Name)
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="BasicInformation.Email" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="BasicInformation.Email" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="BasicInformation.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.BasicInformation.PhoneNumber)
            </div>

           ...
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>`
```

And my page model:

```
 public class BasicInformationFormModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public BasicInformation BasicInformation { get; set; }

        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            return Page();
        }

        public IActionResult OnPost(BasicInformation basicInformation)
        {
            // all data from separate views / editors need to be present in basicInformation
            return Page();
        }
    }
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47952259/using-partial-view-on-asp-net-core-razor-pages

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a model class to warp the `BasicInformation` model,

```
public class ProfileViewModel{
       public BasicInformation BasicInformation {get;set;}
}
```

and than make view as strongly type with model `ProfileViewModel`

```
@model ProfileViewModel
```

Comment: here I work with Pages. The focus is on separation. I need another view for Name, PhoneNumber, but when I execute the Post method, to receive BasicInformation object that contains all of the information from other views